# SQL : Max date available for a given date

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera

I want to calculate maximum date for `cash_date` column, and if is it null it should populate latest date available.

SQL script:

```
select 
       calendar_day
       ,cash_date
from dates_manager
where year(calendar_day)=2019
      and month(calendar_day)=11
group by 
        calendar_day
        ,cash_date
```

[image]

expected

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this?

It will get only those data where `cash_data` is not Null.

```
select 
calendar_day
,cash_date
from dates_manager
where year(calendar_day)=2019
and month(calendar_day)=11 and cash_date IS NOT NULL
group by 
calendar_day
,cash_date
```

As per your question,

your query is fine,

now as you get the result,

Just get it your code and there you can process and replace the null value with the max date you get.

Or else you can try below code to get the result

```
select 
calendar_day
,max(cash_date)
from dates_manager
where year(calendar_day)=2019
and month(calendar_day)=11 and cash_date IS NOT NULL
group by 
calendar_day
,cash_date
```

Comment: Hello,
because i need to keep my calendar_day date 2019-11-10 in my dataset so your solution doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Calculate max date using analytic function and substitute if null:

```
select 
     calendar_day,
     nvl(cash_date, max_cash_date) as cash_date 
from
(
select 
       calendar_day
       ,cash_date
       ,max(cash_date) over(partition by year(calendar_day), month(calendar_day) order by calendar_day rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as max_cash_date
from dates_manager
where year(calendar_day)=2019
      and month(calendar_day)=11
)s
group by 
        calendar_day
        ,nvl(cash_date, max_cash_date)
```

Comment: that give me the max value date and not the latest available value date

Comment: @GuillaumeMagnan  added window to check only rows before current

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `LAST_VALUE`, documented here: http://dwgeek.com/hadoop-hive-analytic-functions-examples.html/ and here: https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-11-x/topics/impala_analytic_functions.html

```
select 
  calendar_day,
  last_value(cash_date ignore nulls) over (order by calendar_day) as cash_day
from dates_manager
where year(calendar_day) = 2019 and month(calendar_day) = 11
order by calendar_day;
```

I've added the `ORDER BY` clause your query was missing. And I removed the `GROUP BY` clause, as the query contains no aggregation functions. In case there can be multiple entries per day in the table, you'll have to adjust my query accordingly.

Comment: it doesn't work, i still have NULL value for my calendar_day 2019-11-10 :/

Comment: My bad, sorry; I missed the `IGNORE NULLS` clause. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For information, i succeeded to solve my issue simply with:
MAX(cash_date) OVER (ORDER BY calendar_day ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max()` as a window function:

```
select dm.calendar_day,
       coalesce(dm.cash_date, max(dm.cash_date) over (order by dm.calendar_day)) as cash_date
from dates_manager dm
where year(calendar_day) = 2019 and
      month(calendar_day) = 11
group by dm.calendar_day, dm.cash_date;
```