# Postgres SQL Query - If table 1 date does not match table 2 date then grab the max date available from table 2 at that time

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the picture below, Table 1 and 2 are made up of subqueries full of proprietary fields. I'm trying to figure out the best way to produce the query output on the right but am not sure if I should be writing a boolean statement in the `JOIN` clause or in the `WHERE` clause. Even then, I'm not aware of a good `CTE` or `CASE` statement that would get the job done.

The only solution I can think of is to take the existing query and convert the whole thing into yet another subquery where I just take the `MAX()` available History Date by means of a Cartesian Join.

How do I produce the query in the best way?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58852339/sql-max-date-available-for-a-given-date) and this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190815/get-rows-with-most-recent-date-for-each-different-item) are similar but don't quite get the job done.

[image: Query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lateral join to select the `max(history_date)` date which is less than or equal the `week_start_date`.

```
select t1.week_start_date, t2.history_date  
   from table1 t1  
   join lateral (select max(history_date) history_date 
                   from table2  
                   where history_date <= t1.week_start_date
                ) t2 
             on true;
```

**NOTE:** Not tested. I cannot copy/past data from an image.

Comment: I had to tweak it a little to bring in the rest of the fields I need (that I didn't include in the question) but it worked!